# listView Как вывести в Excel все его столбцы и их данные

Tags: c#

проблема в том что этот код выводит только данные этих столбцов, а названия самих столбцов не выводит.

```
 private void excell_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel mon|*.xls", ValidateNames = true })
        {
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
                Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)app.ActiveSheet;
                app.Visible = false;
                foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        for (int ia = 0; ia < listView1.Columns.Count; ia++)
                            ws.Cells[1, ia + 1] = listView1.Columns[ia].Text;

                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                int i = 2;
                foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
                {

                    ws.Cells[i, 1] = item.SubItems[0].Text;
                    ws.Cells[i, 2] = item.SubItems[1].Text;
                    i++;
                }
                wb.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                app.Quit();
                MessageBox.Show("Ваши данные успешно сохранены.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я не очень понял ваш код. Ткните пальцем плиз, где конкретно вы тут записываете названия слобцов в документ?

Comment: @tym32167 где *\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ помечено

Comment: а у вас вот тут `listView1.Items` хранятся названия колонок? Вы же в следующем цикле значения из того же самого списка записываете.

Comment: и ещё момент. Вы в первом цикле пишете данные в те же самые ячейки. То есть вы вот эту `ws.Cells[1, 1]` и вот эту `ws.Cells[1, 2]` ячейки просто много раз перезаписваете. Вероятно это не то, что вам надо

Comment: @tym32167 скорее всего, но я не знаю как сделать что бы работал. Я добавил картинки

Comment: ну, я всего кода не вижу, но вам скорее всего надо удалить первый цикл и написать вместо него что то типа `ws.Cells[1, 1] = listView1.Columns[0].Text;` и `ws.Cells[1, 2] = listView1.Columns[1].Text;`

Comment: @tym32167 помогло, вопрос еще, у меня там колонок может быть 5 или 10 или больше, как сделать заполнение автоматически чтобы не писать много раз  ws.Cells[1, 1] = listView1.Columns[0].Text;                    ws.Cells[1, 2] =  listView1.Columns[1].Text;

Comment: Конечно попробуйте `for(int i=0; i<listView1.Columns.Count; i++) ws.Cells[1, i] = listView1.Columns[i].Text;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам скорее всего надо удалить первый цикл, он бесполезный.

Также, чтобы указать 2 первые колонки

```
ws.Cells[1, 1] = listView1.Columns[0].Text;
ws.Cells[1, 2] = listView1.Columns[1].Text;
```

Чтобы указать все колонки

```
for(int i=0; i<listView1.Columns.Count; i++) 
    ws.Cells[1, i+1] = listView1.Columns[i].Text;
```

UPD

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    var value = listView1.Columns[i].Text;// breakpoint ставьте тут     
    ws.Cells[1, i+1] = value;
}
```

UPD 2 - рабочий пример

```
var listView1 = new ListView();

listView1.Columns.Add("one");
listView1.Columns.Add("two");

var item1 = new ListViewItem(); 
item1.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem() {Text = "r_one"});
item1.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem() {Text = "r_two"});    
item1.SubItems.RemoveAt(0);

listView1.Items.Add(item1); 

using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel mon|*.xls", ValidateNames = true })
    {
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)app.ActiveSheet;
        app.Visible = false;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {

            try
            {
                for (int ia = 0; ia < listView1.Columns.Count; ia++)
                    ws.Cells[1, ia + 1] = listView1.Columns[ia].Text;

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        int i = 2;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {

            ws.Cells[i, 1] = item.SubItems[0].Text;
            ws.Cells[i, 2] = item.SubItems[1].Text;
            i++;
        }
        wb.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        app.Quit();
        MessageBox.Show("Ваши данные успешно сохранены.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94485/discussion-on-answer-by-tym32167-listview----excel----).